# ListView keeps repeating/showing same text because of timer

Tags: c#, timer, listbox

I'm making a program to send data true USB. In my program I'm making a list view to show what the program is currently doing.
because I'm working with USB I have a timer with a interval of 50, this causes problems when I want to send text to my list view because my text is send 50 times per second in stead of 1 time.

Anyone any idea how to solve this?
Changing my program so when a text is already written in the listbox the program may not send it again is not an option I think because the same action can happen more than 1 time.

Here you can find relevant code.

```
    private void ClickMyRadioButton1()
    {
        if (radioOff1.Checked)
        {
            radioOff1.PerformClick();
            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem("All USB's are off");
            listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
        }
    }

    private void tmrUSB_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Everything in here is repeated constantly
        USBObject.receiveViaUSB();
        listView1.EnsureVisible(listView1.Items.Count - 1);
        if ( tabPage1 == tabControl1.SelectedTab)
        {
            this.radioOff2.Checked = true;

            if (radioOff1.Checked == true)
            {
                USBObject.fromHostToDeviceBuffer[1] = USB_OFF;
                ClickMyRadioButton1(); //This is what I only want to send one time to my ListBox and not 50 times a second
            }
      }
```

I'm using Visual C# 2010.

Thanks

Comment: if you don't show at least a bit relevant code, then nobody can help you.

Comment: Please take a look at [ask].

Comment: Sorry, now you can find relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

try this, let me know if it works for you:

```
    private void ClickMyRadioButton1()
    {
        if (radioOff1.Checked)
        {
            radioOff1.PerformClick();
            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem("All USB's are off");
            listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
        }
    }

    int counter = 0;

    private void tmrUSB_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (counter != 50) 
        {
           counter++;
           return;
        }
        else
        { 
            counter = 0;
        }

        //Everything in here is repeated constantly
        USBObject.receiveViaUSB();
        listView1.EnsureVisible(listView1.Items.Count - 1);
        if ( tabPage1 == tabControl1.SelectedTab)
        {
            this.radioOff2.Checked = true;

            if (radioOff1.Checked == true)
            {
                USBObject.fromHostToDeviceBuffer[1] = USB_OFF;
                ClickMyRadioButton1(); //This is what I only want to send one tine to my ListBox
            }
      }
```

Comment: I tried this but this is not a solution.
This just makes my system slower, so the text will now be sended less often but my USB communication is now also really slow which is not acceptable for my application.
I think I need to find an other solution.. But no idea how :/
But thanks anyway for your help.